# How to sort based on date-like substring?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have one column in a table in which there's some data like this:

```
TBSPL/C/Mar12/634
KBSPL/C/jan14/735
TBDPL/C/aug13/834  
SBSPL/C/july12/034
```

I need to sort the data based on the year in a `GridView`, but I'm getting the problem that the year is stuck in the middle of the value, for example `jan14` in `KBSPL/C/jan14/735`. Because of this, I am not able to sort it by the year.

I tried this, but I'm not having any success:

```
select *
from emp
order by date
```

Comment: Did you try select * from emp order by year(date)

Comment: all values in that columns are in same format as you provided.?

Comment: yes but the date is present in the middle of the row like jan14 like this . .i am not able to do sir

Comment: no mr.Azahar  it is combination of other charcteres like this SBSPL/C/july12/034

Comment: please give me some solution .. SBSPL/C/july12/034  i am not able to sort becos date is in middle of the row  . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do:

```
SELECT * FROM EMP
ORDER BY LEFT(PARSENAME(REPLACE(DATE,'/','.'),2),2)
```

Thanks.

Comment: dear Nesuke, in the database i hav taken the datatype varchar(max) sir